# MySQL STR_TO_DATE function returning NULL

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime

Can anyone please help me to find out solution - I am running following query

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(order_date, '%d-%m-%Y') FROM `order_master`
```

It is returning `NULL` however I have 2 rows in table with values as 'Today' and '15-08-2017' , I want to compare varchar fields with date, tried a lot but could not succeed. Thank you.

Comment: Remember "not working" is not a very useful diagnostic.

Comment: Also "today" is not a valid date.

Comment: @FarhadHemmati - I tried but it is not working

Comment: `SELECT STR_TO_DATE('15-08-2017', '%d-%m-%Y')` has no issues here. Are you sure those values are correct? Keep in mind you should be storing actual `DATE` values in your database whenever possible doing the conversion on insertion.

Comment: The most important thing when getting help here is to explain what you need and what problems you're having **in terms of undesirable results**. When you say "not working", which you just did again, you're not telling us anything. Maybe it's working fine but you just don't expect it to work that way. Explain **what it did** in terms as specific as possible without being verbose. "Returning `NULL`" is a good example of sufficiently specific.

Comment: Okay @tadman , I understood your point, actually I want to compare varchar field to date, I tried "SELECT * FROM activity_emp
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(server_date_time, '%d/%m/%Y')
  BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('29/08/2012', '%d/%m/%Y')
    AND STR_TO_DATE('07/10/2012', '%d/%m/%Y')" but it is not working

Comment: A) Whenever possible use `DATE` fields in your database. Comparing with a function is often punishingly slow because every row must be evaluated. B) What does **not working** mean? Please, stop saying that. It's super frustrating. C) You've got `/` in this example, `-` in the other. Which format is used? D) There's no reason to use `STR_TO_DATE` on a static value like that, just put it in as `2012-08-29` and `2012-10-07`.

Comment: if order_date = 15-08-2017 is stored in database, what should this query return - SELECT STR_TO_DATE(order_date, '%d-%m-%Y') FROM `order_master` , please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('15-08-2017', '%d-%m-%Y')
```

works just fine. It yields the `DATE` value `2017-08-15`.

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('Today', '%d-%m-%Y')
```

obviously doesn't. It yields NULL.

You could use something like this to put the present date in place of the `STR_TO_DATE()` result if it came back NULL.

```
SELECT IFNULL(STR_TO_DATE('15-08-2017', '%d-%m-%Y'), CURDATE())
```

But your best bet is to use something like this

```
SELECT IF('Today'=order_date, CURDATE(), STR_TO_DATE(order_date ,'%d-%m-%Y'));
```

This will substitute the current date for an `order_date` value of `Today`, but leave in place the NULL values for other malformed `order_date` values.

Comment: Thank you for your answer , but the problem was 'Collation' of 'order_date' field, it was 'utf32_general_ci' , I changed it to 'utf8_unicode_ci' and it is working now.

Comment: Please include my solution in your answer , it may help others. Thanks much!!